# Network image view's center_crop not working

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview

I am creating `NetworkImageView` programmatically like this:

```
final NetworkImageView niv = new NetworkImageView(context);

        niv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        niv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        niv.setImageUrl("www.example.com/images/example.jpg", imageLoader);
```

but `ScaleType.CENTER_CROP` feature is not working. Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You are using ScaleType from ImageView, you should be using NetworkImageView

```
niv.setScaleType(NetworkImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

I would also set the image url before you scale the image.